# Returning from mongoose query to parent function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, callback

I have a function that takes a string of usernames, splits them at the comma and then has to check if that username exists within the database and if so put its ID in an array.

```
module.exports = function (peopleString) {
let people = peopleString.split(',')
for (person in people) {
    people[person] = people[person].replace(/ /g,'')

    users.findOne({username: people[person]}, function (err, document) 
    {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            if (!document) {
                people.splice(person, 1)
            }

            people[person] = document._id
        })
    }

    return people
}
```

The problem is that before all the query's are made the function has already returned because mongoose is async. How do i make this work while still using the return off the exported function to return the array of user id's?

Answer (score 0):

You could find all matching docs in one go and return the promise:

```
module.exports = function (peopleString) {

  // Split string into array
  let people = peopleString
    .split(',')
    .map(person => person.replace(/ /g,''))

  // Find all users where username matched any value in the array
  // Return a promise which will eventually resolve to an array of ids
  return users
    .find({ username: { $in: people } })
    .then(docs => docs.map(doc => doc._id))

}
```

...and then you can handle the returned promise where you use the function like this:

```
// Import your function
const getUserIds = require('./get-user-ids')

// Your string of people
const peopleString = ' ... '

// Call then/catch on the eventual result
getUserIds(peopleString)
  .then(ids => {
    // Handle results
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Handle error
  })
```

I hope this helps.